# Python one line if else

Tags: python, if-statement

Whats the wrong syntax in the code below?  Shouldn't this line work? Can someone explain why its not working and whats the correct syntax.

```
return [ True for x in numbers if x == 3 else False ]
```

Comment: The `if` after the `for` is **for filtering**.

Comment: It is not working because the syntax is wrong. The solution is to look up the  syntax.

Comment: `if ... else` should be before the `for`... 

  Alternatively using `[x == 3 for x in numbers]` is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need

```
[ x == 3 for x in numbers ]
```

This will iterate over each element in `numbers` and compare it to `3`, returning `True` or `False` for each element. (Note that there's no need to use the `if...else` construct when you're only returning `True` and `False`. The `==` operator already does that.)

For example:

```
>>> numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
>>> [ x == 3 for x in numbers ]
[False, False, True, False, False]
```

Your syntax is incorrect because an `if` statement *after* the `for` loop in a list generator is used to filter elements out. For example:

```
>>> [ True for x in numbers if x == 3 ]
[True]
```

In this case, elements that don't meet the criteria `if x == 3` aren't included in the output at all.

Comment: In a particular case this can be a substitute. But this method is limited only by a binary value and is not a replacement for a ternary operator in a list generator.

Answer (score 0):

if you need using ternary operator in list generator:

```
[ True if x == 3 else False for x in numbers ]
```

Comment: "*Can someone explain why its not working and ...*" how is this answering that question?

Comment: This solves the problem of using a ternary operator in a list generator. And it does not work for obvious reason, in the generator the condition is used as a filter, but there is inserted a ternary operator

Comment: if it was an *obvious* reason, then why does the OP asks that?